# Loading a C++ class with polymorphism using dlsym()

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism, dlsym

I have a C++ program which I need to open a shared object (.so) and load a C++ class from it. I have seen this done on the internet and I have loaded many things using dlsym() in both C and C++, so I know how everything works. However, there is a slight difference I need to make. The class I am loading with dlsym() must be a child class of another class which is defined in a header used by both the shared object and the main program. The idea is to load a bunch of different custom versions of this class at runtime. Linking with the object at compile-time is not an option. Here is what I have done (heavily abbreviated, but all the important parts are there):

BaseClass.h:

```
class BaseClass {
    public:
        virtual ~BaseClass();
        virtual int function(int, int);
};
```

ChildClass.h:

```
extern "C" BaseClass* makechild();
```

ChildClass.cpp:

```
class ChildClass : public BaseClass {
    public:
        int function(int a, int b) override { return a + b; }
};

BaseClass* makechild() {
    return new ChildClass();
}
```

main.cpp:

```
std::function<BaseClass*(void)> make;

// note that in the actual program I throw a std::runtime_error with
// dlerror() as its message when this goes wrong, and I don't handle it
make = reinterpret_cast<BaseClass*(*)(void)>(dlsym(handle, "makechild"));

BaseClass* myclass = make();
```

I then compile the ChildClass.cpp as ChildClass.so (using `-shared -fpic`) and I compile main.cpp with `-ldl` and some other warning-related flags and such. Using g++ and clang++ I get two different errors at runtime:

- After compiling with clang++: `undefined symbol: _ZN9BaseClassD2Ev`
- After compiling with g++: `undefined symbol: _ZTI9BaseClass`

After checking the .so file with objdump and readelf, I confirm that this symbol is indeed undefined:

```
...
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000              _ZN9BaseClassD2Ev
...
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000              _ZTI9BaseClass
...
```

I am not sure what these symbols mean exactly. After a little bit of reading of the ABI docs, it seems the first might be a dtor or something, and the second is probably the ctor or the class itself, something like that. In any case, I am not explicitly trying to load these, but I am not sure why they are undefined. Is it possible to do this polymorphism/inheritance setup with dlsym() and C++?

**Edit:** Thanks to a comment, I have used the C++filt program to find out that the destructor was missing (I just added `virtual ~BaseClass() = default;` to fix that). Now the one thing missing is the `_ZTI` one, which is the typeinfo for the class.

Comment: use command `echo _ZTI9BaseClass | c++filt` to demangle that name

Comment: You need to provide a definition for the `BaseClass` destructor.

Comment: @Slava Thanks! This is a really helpful command, I didn't know about it.

Comment: @G.M. I have now done that, but the missing item now is still `_ZTI9BaseClass`, which appears to be the type info for the base class.

Comment: You may need to link main progarm with flag `-Wl,--export-all-symbols`

Comment: @Slava I am doing that, otherwise `-ldl` doesn't work at all with g++.

Comment: Is `BaseClass::function` implemented?

Comment: @G.M. Actually, I thought it was, but it turns out it's not. I forgot to add `= 0` to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the destructor and the typeinfo were the symbols which were undefined. Given how many times I've done things like this, I should have seen that, but nobody's perfect. Anyway, all I did to fix this was add `= default` for `BaseClass::~BaseClass` and `= 0` for `BaseClass::function`. Thanks a lot to user G.M. in the comments on my original post for bringing this up!